# Code that compiles in Arduino IDE does not compile in Atom PlatformIO

Tags: arduino, atom-editor

I have just started using Atom PlatformIO and am trying to get a  basic menu to run using a rotary encoder. The code compiles and uploads when using the Arduino IDE, but does not compile when in the Atom Platform IO. The errors are as follows:

```
'PinA' was not declared in this scopeat line 38 col 22
'PinB' was not declared in this scopeat line 39 col 21
'rotaryMenu' was not declared in this scopeat line 47 col 14
enter code here'setAdmin' was not declared in this scopeat line 99 col 24
'setAdmin' was not declared in this scopeat line 104 col 24
'setAdmin' was not declared in this scopeat line 109 col 24
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
EDIT: I fixed the rotaryMenu, setAdmin errors by using function prototypes. I still have the errors with attachInterrupt to PinA and PinB.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

When I look through the code, all of these things have been declared before being used. What am I missing?

Here is the code being used:

```
#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif
/*******Interrupt-based Rotary Encoder Menu Sketch*******
 * by Simon Merrett, based on insight from Oleg Mazurov, Nick Gammon,     rt and Steve Spence, and code from Nick Gammon
 * 3,638 bytes with debugging on UNO, 1,604 bytes without debugging
 */
// Rotary encoder declarations
static int pinA = 2; // Our first hardware interrupt pin is digital pin 2
static int pinB = 3; // Our second hardware interrupt pin is digital pin 3
volatile byte aFlag = 0; // let's us know when we're expecting a rising edge on pinA to signal that the encoder has arrived at a detent
volatile byte bFlag = 0; // let's us know when we're expecting a rising edge on pinB to signal that the encoder has arrived at a detent (opposite direction to when aFlag is set)
volatile byte encoderPos = 0; //this variable stores our current value of encoder position. Change to int or uin16_t instead of byte if you want to record a larger range than 0-255
volatile byte oldEncPos = 0; //stores the last encoder position value so we can compare to the current reading and see if it has changed (so we know when to print to the serial monitor)
volatile byte reading = 0; //somewhere to store the direct values we read from our interrupt pins before checking to see if we have moved a whole detent
// Button reading, including debounce without delay function declarations
const byte buttonPin = 4; // this is the Arduino pin we are connecting the push button to
byte oldButtonState = HIGH;  // assume switch open because of pull-up resistor
const unsigned long debounceTime = 10;  // milliseconds
unsigned long buttonPressTime;  // when the switch last changed state
boolean buttonPressed = 0; // a flag variable
// Menu and submenu/setting declarations
byte Mode = 0;   // This is which menu mode we are in at any given time (top level or one of the submenus)
const byte modeMax = 3; // This is the number of submenus/settings you want
byte setting1 = 0;  // a variable which holds the value we set
byte setting2 = 0;  // a variable which holds the value we set
byte setting3 = 0;  // a variable which holds the value we set
/* Note: you may wish to change settingN etc to int, float or boolean to suit your application.
 Remember to change "void setAdmin(byte name,*BYTE* setting)" to match and probably add some
 "modeMax"-type overflow code in the "if(Mode == N && buttonPressed)" section*/

void setup() {
  //Rotary encoder section of setup
      pinMode(pinA, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pinA as an input, pulled HIGH to the logic voltage (5V or 3.3V for most cases)
      pinMode(pinB, INPUT_PULLUP); // set pinB as an input, pulled HIGH to the logic voltage (5V or 3.3V for most cases)
      attachInterrupt(0,* PinA, RISING);//(0,PinA,RISING); // set an interrupt on PinA, looking for a rising edge signal and executing the "PinA" Interrupt Service Routine (below)
  attachInterrupt(1,PinB,RISING); // set an interrupt on PinB, looking for a rising edge signal and executing the "PinB" Interrupt Service Routine (below)
  // button section of setup
  pinMode (buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); // setup the button pin
  // DEBUGGING section of setup
  Serial.begin(9600);     // DEBUGGING: opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
    }

void loop() {
  rotaryMenu();
  // carry out other loop code here
}

void rotaryMenu() { //This handles the bulk of the menu functions without needing to install/include/compile a menu library
  //DEBUGGING: Rotary encoder update display if turned
  if(oldEncPos != encoderPos) { // DEBUGGING
    Serial.println(encoderPos);// DEBUGGING. Sometimes the serial  monitor may show a value just outside modeMax due to this function. The menu shouldn't be affected.
    oldEncPos = encoderPos;// DEBUGGING
  }// DEBUGGING
  // Button reading with non-delay() debounce - thank you Nick Gammon!
  byte buttonState = digitalRead (buttonPin);
  if (buttonState != oldButtonState){
    if (millis () - buttonPressTime >= debounceTime){ // debounce
      buttonPressTime = millis ();  // when we closed the switch
      oldButtonState =  buttonState;  // remember for next time
      if (buttonState == LOW){
        Serial.println ("Button closed"); // DEBUGGING: print that button has been closed
        buttonPressed = 1;
      }
      else {
        Serial.println ("Button opened"); // DEBUGGING: print that button has been opened
        buttonPressed = 0;
      }
    }  // end if debounce time up
  } // end of state change

  //Main menu section
  if (Mode == 0) {
    if (encoderPos > (modeMax+10)) encoderPos = modeMax; // check we haven't gone out of bounds below 0 and correct if we have
    else if (encoderPos > modeMax) encoderPos = 0; // check we haven't gone out of bounds above modeMax and correct if we have
    if (buttonPressed){
      Mode = encoderPos; // set the Mode to the current value of input if button has been pressed
      Serial.print("Mode selected: "); //DEBUGGING: print which mode has been selected
      Serial.println(Mode); //DEBUGGING: print which mode has been  selected
      buttonPressed = 0; // reset the button status so one press results in one action
  if (Mode == 1) {
        Serial.println("Mode 1"); //DEBUGGING: print which mode has been selected
        encoderPos = setting1; // start adjusting Vout from last set point
  }
  if (Mode == 2) {
      Serial.println("Mode 2"); //DEBUGGING: print which mode has been selected
      encoderPos = setting2; // start adjusting Imax from last set point
      }
  if (Mode == 3) {
        Serial.println("Mode 3"); //DEBUGGING: print which mode has been selected
        encoderPos = setting3; // start adjusting Vmin from last set point
      }
    }
  }
  if (Mode == 1 && buttonPressed) {
    setting1 = encoderPos; // record whatever value your encoder has been turned to, to setting 3
    setAdmin(1,setting1);
    //code to do other things with setting1 here, perhaps update display
  }
  if (Mode == 2 && buttonPressed) {
    setting2 = encoderPos; // record whatever value your encoder has been turned to, to setting 2
    setAdmin(2,setting2);
    //code to do other things with setting2 here, perhaps update display
  }
  if (Mode == 3 && buttonPressed){
    setting3 = encoderPos; // record whatever value your encoder has  been turned to, to setting 3
    setAdmin(3,setting3);
    //code to do other things with setting3 here, perhaps update display
      }
}

// Carry out common activities each time a setting is changed
void setAdmin(byte name, byte setting){
  Serial.print("Setting "); //DEBUGGING
  Serial.print(name); //DEBUGGING
  Serial.print(" = "); //DEBUGGING
  Serial.println(setting);//DEBUGGING
  encoderPos = 0; // reorientate the menu index - optional as we have   overflow check code elsewhere
  buttonPressed = 0; // reset the button status so one press results     in one action
  Mode = 0; // go back to top level of menu, now that we've set values
  Serial.println("Main Menu"); //DEBUGGING
}

//Rotary encoder interrupt service routine for one encoder pin
void PinA(){
  cli(); //stop interrupts happening before we read pin values
  reading = PIND & 0xC; // read all eight pin values then strip away    all but pinA and pinB's values
  if(reading == B00001100 && aFlag) { //check that we have both pins     at detent (HIGH) and that we are expecting detent on this pin's rising edge
    encoderPos --; //decrement the encoder's position count
    bFlag = 0; //reset flags for the next turn
    aFlag = 0; //reset flags for the next turn
  }
  else if (reading == B00000100) bFlag = 1; //signal that we're expecting pinB to signal the transition to detent from free rotation
  sei(); //restart interrupts
}

//Rotary encoder interrupt service routine for the other encoder pin
void PinB(){
  cli(); //stop interrupts happening before we read pin values
  reading = PIND & 0xC; //read all eight pin values then strip away all but pinA and pinB's values
  if (reading == B00001100 && bFlag) { //check that we have both pins at detent (HIGH) and that we are expecting detent on this pin's rising edge
    encoderPos ++; //increment the encoder's position count
bFlag = 0; //reset flags for the next turn
aFlag = 0; //reset flags for the next turn
   }
      else if (reading == B00001000) aFlag = 1; //signal that we're expecting pinA to signal the transition to detent from free rotation
      sei(); //restart interrupts
    }
    // end of sketch!
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have fixed the problem. I discovered that I had some old files from another project in the "src" folder. Atom was trying to compile them as part of the code.
Removed them from the "src" folder and it compiles now.

Valuable lesson learned.